# How to diff Windows permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, diff

I have a small issue with Windows permissions (or rather, I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue which I think has to do with Windows permissions) and would like to compare and contrast permissions on different machines (one does not have the issue and one does), is there a tool that can do this for me?  Or some hidden functionality that I don't know about?

In Linux I'd do ls -l, dump it into a file and use the diff command, what about Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Try the `cacls` utility (`cacls /?` for usage).  There are a couple of different versions, depending on your version of Windows be it XP, Vista, 7, or 8, so you may need/want to use `xcacls` (XP) or `icacls` (Vista / Win7 / Win8).

Comment: You want `icacls * /T`, probably. icacls is in Vista too.